# tensor field induce a multilinear map

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds, tensor-products

Prove the following:

> If $A$ is a smooth covariant k-tensor field on smooth manifold $M$. Then the map
> $$F:\mathcal{X}(M)\times...\times \mathcal{X}(M) \to C^\infty(M)$$
> (where $\mathcal{X}(M)$ is set of all smooth vector field on $M$) defined as $$A(X_1,...,X_k)(p) = A_p(X_1|_p,...,X_k|_p)$$ is a multilinear function over $C^\infty(M)$.

My attempt:

It's sufficient to show to each $i$ ,
$$A(X_1,...,fX_i+f'X'_i ,...,X_k) = fA(X_1,...,X_if'X'_i ,...,X_k)+f'A(X_1,...,X'_i ,...,X_k)$$

To do this evaluate at each point $p$. But before that first write $A$ as component representation at local chart:

$$A(X_1,...,fX_i+f'X'_i ,...,X_k) = A_{j_1j_2...,j_k}dx^{j_1}(X_1)...dx^{j_i}(fX_k+f'X'_k)...dx^k(X_k)$$

Now evaluate it at point $p$, the right hand side is

$$ A_{j_1j_2...,j_k}(p)dx^{j_1}(X_1|_p)...dx^{j_i}(f(p)X_i|_p+f'(p)X'_i|_p)...dx^k(X_k|_p) \\=f(p)A_{j_1j_2...,j_k}(p)dx^{j_1}(X_1|_p)...dx^{j_i}(X_i|_p)...dx^k(X_k|_p)+\\f'(p)A_{j_1j_2...,j_k}(p)dx^{j_1}(X_1|_p)...dx^{j_i}(X'_i|_p)...dx^k(X_k|_p)$$

So it holds for all $p$,which implies it's multilinear in $C^\infty(M)$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You can show it directly without coordinates and its simpler.

Comment: @Si Kucing thank you ,Since $A_p$ is element in the tensor space over $T^*_pM$ and we know tensor space is set of multilinear map, correct?